# How to pass by reference in this case?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I try to use the `change()` function to change the content of `y`.
I want to ask why `y` cannot change when I remove the `*` when assigning `x` to `"abc"`?

Also, I found that `&*x` is the same as `&y`, does that mean the address of pointer `x` is assigned to be the same as the address of the content that `*y` pointed to? Also, why `&x` does not equals to `"abc"`?

***My Code:***

```
void change(char *x) {
    *x = "abc";
    printf("S3: %x\n", &x);
    printf("S4: %x\n", &*x);
}

int main() {
    char *y = "def"; 
    printf("S1: %x\n", &y);
    printf("S2: %x\n", &*y);
    change(&y);
    printf("result: %s\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *can't* legally change the "content" of `y`because it's pointing to a string-literal.

Comment: `*x="abc"`??? `-Wall` it.

Comment: Why are you compiling with warnings disabled?

Comment: The string literals `"abc"` and `"def"` are of type `const char*`.  As well as other errors, you're mixing incompatible types.

Comment: Is this question about C or is it about C++?

Comment: @Jason `The string literals "abc" and "def" are of type const char*`...any reference to this?

Comment: @Jason They're not pointers, they're __arrays__ of type `const char[]` in C++, `char[]` in C (even though it's UB to modify them).

Comment: This code doesn't compile in either C or C++. Please decide what language you're using, make the code compile in that language, and remove the tag for the other language.

Answer (score 5):

There are many issues in your code, to point out some of them

1. `y` points to a *string literal*. Any attempt to modify a string literal is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. To print an address, use `%p` format specifier, with a cast to `(void*)` for the argument, Using incorrect type of argument is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Similarly, to print a `char`, you need `%c`, to print a string you need `%s`. Read more [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)
3. Inside `change()` function, `*x` is of type `char`, and you're trying to assign a pointer (base address of the string literal `"abc"`) to it.

*Enough!! Ask your compiler to tell you 'bout the rest.* (In other words, please enable compiler warnings and try to fix the reported issues.)

Answer (score 2):

> why &x does not equals to "abc"?

Because `&x` gives address of `x` not value it points to . To get value you need `*x`.

`y` can't be changed because it points to string literals which is constant . Any try to change it will cause UB.

> does that mean the address of pointer x is assigned to be the same as the address of the content that *y pointed to?

Pointer `x` has address of pointer `y` as you pass in function the address of `y` as argument.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read more about pointers and parameters passing.
A pointer is a variable that holds **the address in memory** of another variable.
When you refer to a variable in your code the compiler use **the value** of such variable, for this reason when you refer to a pointer you'll get its content that is an address.

The operator `&` give back the address of a variable, so in the snippet:

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
```

The pointer `p` will hold the memory address of variable `a`. If we use the operator `*` on `p` we will get the content of the memory address hold by `a`:

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

Will print `10`.

If we write `&*p`, while it is not fully correct and many compilers will even issue a warning, we are getting **the value pointed to by the pointer, and than requiring the address of that content**, that is to have back again the address of data that is the content of the pointer.

Now the functions, when you pass a parameter in a function a copy of the variable is pushed on the stack from where will be accessed inside the function.
These values are local and any change made to them is lost when you leave the function. Of course if you pass a pointer, the address of your variable, then change the value using the pointer you can reflect the change on the real variable.

But you made a big error in your code, while you are declaring a pointer to char in your function proto:

```
void change(char *x)
```

You are passing `change(&y);` that is a `char **` (`y` is a `char *`, `&y` is a `char **`). You should have got a lot of warnings for that.
Anyway the concept is correct on the caller side, you pass the address where is stored the address of your string, changing it `y` will point to the new string. It is perfectly legal because you're updating a pointer with another constant string (not changing a constant string that is illegal).
But you need the address of the pointer to the string, your function must be:

```
void change(char **x)
{
    *x = "abc";
    printf("S3: %p\n", (void *)&x);
    printf("S4: %p\n", (void *)&*x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *y = "def"; 
    printf("S1: %p\n", (void *)&y);
    printf("S2: %p\n", &*y);
    change(&y);
    printf("result: %s\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Last use the correct formatting in `printf` for pointer it is `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `change(y)` not `change(&y)`, `change(&y)` is address of `*y` not address in y. So y gives address of first character in a string, where &y gives address to y not address to first string.

HTH

Comment: What does `HTH` mean? Also, please improve formatting and content (i.e. add more explanation).

Comment: HTH --> hope this helps